# How to set _controller.nextPage() for all Carousel Sliders?

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel

I started with Flutter [`carousel_slider` example](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider/example) and I started experimenting with it. I have 2 questions about this project.

1. When I click the `Random` or `Next` button it only affects the last slider. How can I fix it to change all slides at the same time?
2. How can I click the image and redirect to another page related to that picture?

```
class ManuallyControlledSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {return _ManuallyControlledSliderState();
  }
  // _ManuallyControlledSliderState createState() => _ManuallyControlledSliderState();
}

class _ManuallyControlledSliderState extends State<ManuallyControlledSlider> {
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();
  final rng = Random();
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Manually controlled slider')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              CarouselSlider(
                items: imageSliders,
                options: CarouselOptions(height: 100,viewportFraction: 1),
                carouselController: _controller,
              ),
              CarouselSlider(
                items: imageSliders,
                options: CarouselOptions(height: 100,viewportFraction: 1),
                carouselController: _controller,
              ),
              CarouselSlider(
                items: imageSliders,
                options: CarouselOptions(height: 100,viewportFraction: 1),
                carouselController: _controller,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => _controller.animateToPage(rng.nextInt(imgList.length)),
                      child: Text('Random'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => _controller.nextPage(),
                      child: Text('→'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need 3 separated controllers to change all sliders at the same time. About going to another page on click use the [`GestureDetector`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and [`Navigator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) classes.

Check it out:

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
class _ManuallyControlledSliderState extends State<ManuallyControlledSlider> {
  final CarouselController _controller1 = CarouselController();
  final CarouselController _controller2 = CarouselController();
  final CarouselController _controller3 = CarouselController();
  final rng = Random();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Manually controlled slider')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              CarouselSlider(
                items: imageSliders,
                options: CarouselOptions(height: 100, viewportFraction: 1),
                carouselController: _controller1,
              ),
              CarouselSlider(
                items: imageSliders,
                options: CarouselOptions(height: 100, viewportFraction: 1),
                carouselController: _controller2,
              ),
              CarouselSlider(
                items: imageSliders,
                options: CarouselOptions(height: 100, viewportFraction: 1),
                carouselController: _controller3,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        final index = rng.nextInt(imgList.length);
                        _controller1.animateToPage(index);
                        _controller2.animateToPage(index);
                        _controller3.animateToPage(index);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Random'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _controller1.nextPage();
                        _controller2.nextPage();
                        _controller3.nextPage();
                      },
                      child: const Text('→'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Random for all slides now working and i figure it out how to use it properly. But i didn’t  solve GestureDetector problem i cant click the images. When i add GestureDetector to widget i got error like “bottom overflowed by infinity pixels” how can i fix it ? do you have any suggestion for it ?

Comment: my bad i added it. But now i can't find image map ?
`
 GestureDetector(
                child: CarouselSlider(
                  items: imageSliders,
                  options: CarouselOptions(height: 100, viewportFraction: 1),
                  carouselController: _controller1,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push<Widget>(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => imagesc(imgList[item])));
                  },
              ),
`

imgList[0] works but shows only first image on new page