# How to slide two carousel sliders in flutter at the same time in flutter? as when the first one changes the second does too

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to make parallel carousel sliders that changes when the first one change. My first approach was to take the index from the first one and inject it in the second but I was not able to do that. The second approach was to use the same controller but obviously that didn't work. Did anyone ever do that please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
      SizedBox(
          height: ...,
          width: .... ,
          child: CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: count,
              itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                return StationItem(
                    station: allSectors.where((item) => item.iD == selectedSectorId).first.stations![index],
                    stationNumber: index+1,
                    changePage: _changePage,
                    changeTitle: _changeTitle);
              },
              carouselController: stationsCarouselController,
              options: CarouselOptions(
                onScrolled: (index){
                  setState(() => activeIndex = index as int);
                },
                initialPage: 0,
                onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                  setState(() => activeIndex = index);
                },
                viewportFraction: 1,
                enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
              )),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: ...,
              height: ...,
            ),
            SizedBox(
                width: ...,
                height: ...,
                child: FittedBox(
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: _next,
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/icons/Right_arrow.png'),
                        splashRadius:...))),
            SizedBox(
              width: ...,
              height: ...,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: ...,
          width: ...,
        ),
        SizedBox(
            height: ...,
            width: ...,

            child: AbsorbPointer(
              child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                  itemCount: count,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                    return StationLoadingImage(station: allSectors.where((item) => item.iD == selectedSectorId).first.stations![index]);
                  },
                  carouselController: stationsImageCarouselController,
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    initialPage: activeIndex,
                    onScrolled: null,
                    onPageChanged: null,
                    viewportFraction: 1,
                    enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                    enlargeCenterPage: true,
                  )),
            )
        )
```

'''

Comment: I tried using buttons instead of sliding. It worked when disabling the other carousel by using 'AbsorbPointer' so the user cannot slide the other one and only the buttons of the first changes the second. But there is still a problem when changing the first one with sliding the second does not. Please not that the first slider's elements are buttons so the touching can't be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue as you. And then found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73162125/16709479
And that worked for me as well. So, try using two Controllers:

```
final CarouselController _controller1 = CarouselController();
final CarouselController _controller2 = CarouselController();
```

and in the buttons just use both of them like this:

```
_controller1.previousPage(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.linear,
      );
_controller2.previousPage(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.linear,
      );

// For next page:
_controller1.nextPage(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.linear,
      );
_controller2.nextPage(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.linear,
      );
```

It'll help even more if you set `autoplay:false`

Answer (score -1):

```
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
late CarouselController buttonCarouselController =CarouselController(); 

@override 
   void initState() {
buttonCarouselController = CarouselController(length: .., vsync: this);
super.initState();}

@override
    void dispose() {
super.dispose();
_tabController.dispose();
```

}

```
 //You can then define both carouselController as 
carouselController:buttonCarouselController
```